# How to output sqlite3 data in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

Am having issue with how output all records in my `sqlite3`db into `tkinter treeview`.It outputs only the last record in the `db` and also the records doesn't appear at the column specified for it.The `print` method print all the `db` records to my terminal but doesn't output all the records to the `treeview` widget.

Your suggestions are welcome to achieve this

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
First TEXT, Surname TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def View():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM profile")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row) # it print all records in the database
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    conn.close()


connect()  #  this to create the db

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

tree= ttk.Treeview(root, column=("column", "colunn1"))
tree.heading("#0", text="NUMBER")
tree.heading("#1", text="FIRST NAME")
tree.heading("#2", text="SURNAME")
tree.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(text="view data", command=View)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see you create a table but do you insert data into that table before you select?

Comment: @ZackTarr yes the records exit already

Comment: `tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)` is not in the for loop. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: @j_4321 it was typo in the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- The first is that `tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)` is not inside the for loop, so only the last row will be inserted in the treeview.
- The second is that the column `#0` is a special column, and its value is set with `text=...`, not with `values=(...)`. To display correctly your data, you have at least two alternatives:

  - The first is to replace `tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)` by `tree.insert("", tk.END, text=row[0], values=row[1:])`
  - The second is not to use the special column `#0`, you don't need it because you are using the treeview as a table. When you create the tree, use the option `show='headings'` to hide column `#0` and create 3 columns:

    ```
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as tk
    import sqlite3


    def connect():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, First TEXT, Surname TEXT)")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


    def View():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM profile")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row) # it print all records in the database
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
        conn.close()


    connect()  #  this to create the db

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")

    tree= ttk.Treeview(root, column=("column1", "column2", "column3"), show='headings')
    tree.heading("#1", text="NUMBER")
    tree.heading("#2", text="FIRST NAME")
    tree.heading("#3", text="SURNAME")
    tree.pack()

    b2 = tk.Button(text="view data", command=View)
    b2.pack()

    root.mainloop()
    ```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for this!